# HTML table format issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

I currently have a code that looks something like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to alter it so the format looks something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xvmZ.png]

However, it seems like whatever I try, just does not work out. How can I alter my code to make my table look like the one in the image? The CSS, sizes, and shapes don't matter, I'm just struggling to get the correct template.

Comment: The image was not showing because when I tried it, it wouldn't work because I did not have enough reputation. I am new to SOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp):

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to use rowspan, I'll remember this from now on.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is a rowspan tag. Insert the following just after the tbody tag:

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No new row need or should be added to the table here.